# Node.js Express Socket.io server side emit not working

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

I'm using sockets in a chat application and emit works to go client to server, but not server to client. I'm using ejs for templating, chat-footer.ejs is where the client socket is located and it's rendered in message.ejs.

index.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
const port = 3000
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

var username = "";

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit("chat message", msg);
  })
})
app.get("/messages", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(username)
    const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM history');
    const resArr = result.rows;
    res.render('message', {resArr,username
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).send("Error while getting messages");
  }
  })

  app.post('/submit-message',(req, res) => {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()+'-'+today.getFullYear()+" ";
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var am_pm;
    if (hour < 12 && hour != 0){
      am_pm = "am";
    }else if (hour >12){
      am_pm = "pm";
      hour -= 12;
    }else{
      am_pm="pm";
      hour = 12;
    }

    const time = hour + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds()+am_pm;
    const message = req.body.input
     pool.query('INSERT INTO history VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)', [username, message,date,time], (error, result) => {
       if (error) {
         throw error
       }
       
  })
  })

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

message.ejs

```
<%- include('chat-header.ejs') %>
<ul class="messages" id = "message-list">
  <% resArr.forEach(function(message) { %>
    <div class="card my-1" style="width: 40rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
          <p class = "text-muted" style = "float: right;"><%=message.date%><%=message.time%></p>
        <h5 class="card-title text-dark"><%=message.username%></h5>
          <p class="card-text text-muted"><%=message.message%></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% })%>
</ul>
<ul>
  <%- include('chat-footer.ejs') %>
</ul>
```

chat-footer.ejs

```
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"> </label>
    <textarea name = "input" id = "input" placeholder= "Write your message here..." class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" style="width: 36rem;"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Send</button>
</form>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();

    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    temp = document.getElementById('close-button').dataset.username;
    var username = temp;

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var today = new Date();
      var date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()+'-'+today.getFullYear()+" ";
      var hour = today.getHours();
      var am_pm;
      if (hour < 12 && hour != 0){
        am_pm = "am";
      }else if (hour >12){
        am_pm = "pm";
        hour -= 12;
      }else{
        am_pm = "pm";
        hour = 12;
      }
      const time = hour + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds()+am_pm;

      if (input.value) {
        socket.emit('chat message',
        {message:input.value,username:username,date:date,time:time}
        );
      }

      document.getElementById("form").submit();
    });
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
      socket.emit("IM CONNECTED");
    });
</script>
```

When a message is emitted from the client, I know that the server receives it because it's logged to the console. However, I see nothing from the emit from the server back to the client. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
 document.getElementById("form").submit();
```

You are activating the submit button on the form and you get a regular form post done by the browser.  As such, the browser will take the response from that form post and display it in the current window.

Doing that will tear down the existing socket.io connection that belongs to the current web page because that page is being closed.

So, if your server tries to emit to that socket, by the time the request gets to your page (if it even does get there), the page has been replaced by a different page.  Even if that new page opens a new socket.io connection, that won't be the connection that the data was sent on.  In other words, the new page won't get the data either.

If you don't want your page to reload in the browser so that your existing socket.io connection will stay connected, then do your form submission by sending an Ajax request from your Javascript, not by doing a browser-sent form submission.

Also, your `/submit-message` request handler on your server MUST send a response to the request.  Http request handlers that never send any response are a bad thing.  They leave the client hanging, waiting for a response and these connections can pile up for awhile.  Eventually, they will time out, but they create unnecessary resource usage on your server.  If you don't have anything to send back to the client, then just so `res.sendStatus(204)` or something like that or even just `res.send()`.